# PHP Array Grouping on Sponsor Year

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am attempting to generate a grouped array.

Here is my code:

```
function group_assoc($array, $key) {
$return = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
    $return[$v[$key]][] = $v;
}
return $return;
}
```

Here is the current output:

```
Array
(
[2007] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 4
                [showType] => 2
                [categoryID] => 3
                [sponYear] => 2007
                [sponName] => asdasd
                [sponFileName] => design-desktop-wallpaper-2114754569.jpg
            )

    )

[2013] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 2
                [showType] => 1
                [categoryID] => 6
                [sponYear] => 2013
                [sponName] => Test Sponsor
                [sponFileName] => Jellyfish.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 3
                [showType] => 2
                [categoryID] => 1
                [sponYear] => 2013
                [sponName] => asdads
                [sponFileName] => Jellyfish.jpg
            )

    )

)
```

How can I do something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[sponYear] => '2013'
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 4
                [showType] => 2
                [categoryID] => 3
                [sponYear] => 2007
                [sponName] => asdasd
                [sponFileName] => design-desktop-wallpaper-2114754569.jpg
            )

    )

[1] => 
[sponYear] => '2007'
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 2
                [showType] => 1
                [categoryID] => 6
                [sponYear] => 2013
                [sponName] => Test Sponsor
                [sponFileName] => Jellyfish.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sponsorID] => 3
                [showType] => 2
                [categoryID] => 1
                [sponYear] => 2013
                [sponName] => asdads
                [sponFileName] => Jellyfish.jpg
            )

    )

)
```

so that when I run my initial loop for display, I am able to show the 'sponYear'?

Comment: Your expected output isn't formatted well. Can you give a better expected output that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the current output as-is, by changing your foreach loop which consumes it.

```
foreach (group_assoc($input_array, $my_key) as $year => $sponsors) {
    foreach ($sponsors as $sponsor) {
        // Do stuff with $sponsor['sponName'] etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: much obliged,  didn't think of doing it like this, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your arrays in each year are sponsors. So your function would be:

```
function group_assoc($array, $key) {
    $return = array(
        'sponYear' => $key,
        'sponsors' => array()
    );
    foreach($array as $v) {
        $return['sponsors'][] = $v;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: sorry, you just converted it pretty much back to the original array